# Iterate datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a datagrid in my vb.net/wpf application which i create like this:

```
Dim c1 As New DataGridTextColumn()
c1.Header = "Sifra"
c1.Width = 60
c1.Binding = New Binding("Sifra")
gridRacunNew.Columns.Add(c1)

Dim c2 As New DataGridTextColumn()
c2.Header = "Naziv artikla"
c2.Width = 500
c2.Binding = New Binding("Naziv")
gridRacunNew.Columns.Add(c2)

Dim c3 As New DataGridTextColumn()
c3.Header = "Količina"
c3.Width = 50
c3.Binding = New Binding("Kolicina")
gridRacunNew.Columns.Add(c3)

Dim c4 As New DataGridTextColumn()
c4.Header = "Cijena"
c4.Width = 100
c4.Binding = New Binding("Cijena")
gridRacunNew.Columns.Add(c4)

Dim c5 As New DataGridTextColumn()
c5.Header = "Rabat"
c5.Width = 50
c5.Binding = New Binding("Rabat")
gridRacunNew.Columns.Add(c5)

Dim c6 As New DataGridTextColumn()
c6.Header = "PC"
c6.Width = 100
c6.Binding = New Binding("PC")
gridRacunNew.Columns.Add(c6)

Dim c7 As New DataGridTextColumn()
c7.Header = "Iznos"
c7.Width = 100
c7.Binding = New Binding("Iznos")
gridRacunNew.Columns.Add(c7)
```

After i add items to that datagrid i would like to get specific column values for each row, ie: I would like to sumarize "Iznos" values and do 'for each 'sifra''. If i try anything like datagrid.rows IDE tells me that 'rows' is not a member of datagrid

Comment: DataGrid.Items, not Rows. or DataGrid.ItemsSource if there is any

Comment: I hardly recomment to use the MVVM pattern when building WPF applications. A lot easiert and cleaner then using this code behind stuff...

Comment: @ASh How would i in example write code to display a message box for each 'sifra' cell value in datagrid?

Comment: oh, man, please write this in your xaml not by code ! and then work with your object collection, not with the datagrid....